# Update recyclerview item ui in client to indicate that Firebase Database on server got updated

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I'm building a chat app using Firebase Realtime Database. I want to implement the functionality like WhatsApp, where the user can send the message without internet (*Add the message object on RecyclerView*) but will have the clock icon (*To show that the message was not sent yet*).

When the Firebase Database receives the message (*The user device connects to the internet and Firebase sends the message*), I want to update the added element on the recyclerview(*change the clock icon for a positive icon*).

What have I tried? I have that

```
mFirebaseDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    mFirebaseAdapter = new ChatFirebaseAdapter(mFirebaseDatabaseReference.child("chat_id"), user.getId());
recyclerChat.setLayoutManager(mLinearLayoutManager);
    recyclerChat.setAdapter(mFirebaseAdapter);
```

My adapter extends FirebaseRecyclerAdapter from `firebase-ui-database`

I tried to add a `addChildEventListener` on my `DatabaseReference` where I get a `dataSnapshot` of the new element, but I don't know how to get the right position on recyclerview.

```
mFirebaseDatabaseReference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            UPDATE RECYCLERVIEW ITEM
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

I added an `onCompletionListener` when I add a new message, but I don't know how get the right position again.

```
mFirebaseDatabaseReference.push().setValue(message, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
            if (databaseError == null) {
                UPDATE RECYCLERVIEW ITEM
            }
        }
    });
```

Does someone have an idea why I cant accomplish that? Thanks. I search a lot before asked, but I didn't find the right answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution to your problem lies in adding a **delivered** boolean which can be set to **true** and once you receive successful push id from your code in onCompletionListener, then all you need to do is set this boolean to that particular push id.

**Now on your android client in your firebase ui you can check if this boolean is set to true and change the state of recycler view items accordingly.** This solution will work because firebase database is real-time.

**//setting boolean onComplete**

```
mFirebaseDatabaseReference.push().setValue(message, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() { @Override public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) { if (databaseError == null) { databaseReference.child("delivered").setValue(true); } } });
```

*For chat apps like whatsapp, messenger etc you would take another messaging route if not using firebase as backened. Which I am not discussing here as it is out of scope of asked question.*

Comment: Hi Nishant, thanks for the answer. Indeed I am using this tutorial. But don't show how can I check if the server get the message(I achieve that with the listener) and how get the position from recycled view to update the icon

Comment: Your push ids will help you get to correct child. Have a look at edit.

Comment: Yes Nishant, I get the ids of the added child. How can I used that to update the recyclerView. How is the relation of the generate and the position of the item in recycler view. If you could tell me that I will achieve my goal.

Comment: You need to create a view in your recyclerview item that will look for **boolean** Delivered if that is false the view shows a clock if it's true the view shows ticks. Now in your on completion listener when you are getting the push id. Then again you need to get database ref to that push id and change the value of Delivered boolean to True. Now when your database will refresh the view will show ticks reading the value of Delivered. Hope this helps.

Comment: Don't add any listener second time. If you are using firebase database ui your ui will update automatically.

Comment: Thanks Nishant. I thought I had an easier way to do this. I will try what you proposed and if I succeed I will change the problem to resolve. Thanks again.

Comment: The other ways are bit more complex. Considering your initial setup I didn't suggest you to make app local backened with sqlite , custom adapter etc that would be more robust way to achieve stuff. As apps you mentioned use that way. Content providers , sync adapters etc. But I feel this is easiest way to achieve it using firebase ui only.

Comment: So I added a boolean delivered and in populateViewHolder of Adapter I check if the boolean and change the icon. And on the listener I set the boolean true. mFirebaseDatabaseReference.push().setValue(message, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
                if (databaseError == null) {
                    databaseReference.child("delivered").setValue(true);
                }
            }
        });

Comment: Can you edit your answer to the final solution. And if you have time you can detail the robust solution, I will try to implement later.